# All viewport units were converted into pixels after deploy

Tags: css, firebase

I deployed a single-page app using firebase. After deploying all the CSS properties which were defined with viewport units ( vh, vw ) were replaced on their equivalents in pixels ( px ). This completely ruined all the styling. What can be the reason for that?

Comment: Do you use plain CSS or some form of SASS?

Comment: No, i'm using only plain CSS

Comment: Firebase Hosting does not transform content in any way when it is deployed. If you are using any kind of bundler / build step, it might be happening there.